# How to open a new form in a block without reloading whole page?

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms, javascript

I am using Webform with ajax mode. I have added the Webform in block so as only the block is refreshed instead of whole page, it's working fine.

All I want to do is open new form after getting confirmation message without reloading whole page.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "Redirection Location" to "No redirect (reload current page)" in actual webform settings *(/node/x/configure)*. This will show the confirmation message in block without reloading and provide a link "Go back to form" which will reload your form by ajax.